# Using Unicode characters in Excel Series name using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, series

Hey guys I'm trying to set the name of a data series to something that contains Unicode characters, and I'm having a hell of a time. For instance, I want the series name to be this:

ε = n²-k²

I've looked at a handful of posts, but none (that I saw) had a similar situation.  The fact that I'm new to Excel VBA scripts means that I have probably overlooked something simple. I know that the specific chart exists, because this bit of code is just something I've used before that worked with the addition of a few extra bits here and there.  I keep getting the error "Runtime error (1004): Application defined or object-defined error." Here is what I have at the moment:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
Dim chart1 As String
chart1 = "= " & ChrW(&H3B5) & " = n" & ChrW(&HB2) & " - k" & ChrW(&HB2) & " 6-5-2012"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = chart1
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F602")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveSheet.Range("N2:N602")
```

The debugger says that the following line is the cause of the error:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = chart1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
chart1 = ChrW(&H3B5) & " = n" & ChrW(&HB2) & " - k" & ChrW(&HB2) & " 6-5-2012"
```

You are getting that error because it is referring to it as a formula since it starts with an "=" sign

If you want to show the "=" sign then include a space before it. For example

```
chart1 = " = " & ChrW(&H3B5) & " = n" & ChrW(&HB2) & " - k" & _
ChrW(&HB2) & " 6-5-2012"
```

**SNAPSHOT**

A snapshot of both methods.

[image]

Comment: That fixed it! The rest of the chart isn't working (all series on every graph), but I have a feeling that I just need to look up how to use multiple series on one graph to fix that. I was putting that `"= "` in there because that's what recorded macros did, and that's essentially how I learned this.

Comment: @that_physics_guy If this answer helped you then consider accepting it so others can see that your issue was solved.